# Cakephp3.7 Ajax component - 500 error - Template file is missing

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.7

I want to be able to view the ajax result without creating ajax folder and action.ctp file. I am using [dereuromark Ajax Component](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-ajax).

I have configured the application as per below. But I still get 500 error to create ajax folder and action.ctp file.

1. Added `$middlewareQueue->add(\Ajax\Middleware\AjaxMiddleware::class);` to Action.php middleware
2. Set the `RequestHandler` in AppController

   ```
   $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler', [
           'enableBeforeRedirect' => false,
       ]);
   $this->loadComponent('Ajax.Ajax');
   ```
3. My Controller action

   ```
   $content = ['id' => 1, 'title' => 'title'];
   $this->set(compact('content'));
   $this->set('_serialize', ['content']);
   ```
4. **ajax request is working and an I am able to get the result in json.**

Here is the error I get:

```
{
"error":null,
"content":null,
"message":"Template file \"Delegate\/Units\/ajax\/action.ctp\" is missing.",
"url":"\/delegate\/action.json",
"code":500,
"file":"Delegate\/Units\/ajax\/action.ctp",
"line":1565,
"_message":null
}
```

Is there any way that I don't need to create ajax folder and create the action view to see the result through ajax layout.

Comment: Not sure about your problem at the moment, but you shouldn't need both the Ajax middleware and component, they both do the same thing but in different ways.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Thank you for your advise. The problem is I have to keep create `Template/Delegate/ajax/ajaxAction.ctp` file

Comment: Just looked at your code more closely. You're calling `set` from your template? That's not at all how it should be. That should happen in your controller function.

Comment: I am sorry I have updated the question. That is in controller

Comment: If it's in your controller, it should just be `$this->set`, not `$this->Controller->set`.

Comment: @GregSchmidt As I said every thing is working. The only problem is I have to create ajax folder in Templates/Controller_name/ajax/ajax_action_name.ctp. Using Ajax Component I wouldn't need to create ajax view file. But it doesn't work. I mean if I remove the `Templates/Delegate\/Units\/ajax\/action.ctp\` the I get 500 error. action.ctp is missing

Comment: The rendering through the `.ctp` file should be skipped if the `_serialize` variable is set. My best guess from what you've shown is that the `_serialize` variable is *not* being set, because you're using `$this->Controller->set` instead of `$this->set`.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I am sorry. I have updated the question. That was an example which I have taken from Ajax Component Documentation. Trust me I have every thing up and running. The only problem is what I said above

Comment: Have you tried it without the Ajax component, just the middleware?

Comment: Also, can I ask what you mean by adding the middleware "to Action.php middleware"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187899/discussion-between-fury-and-greg-schmidt).